# Passing data without ending a function C# (Creating a facebook's wall)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hey i am supposed to do a user activity log for a forum on each user profile (something similar to facebook's wall), i tried to make some huge database request but the efficiency is disappointing so i have to find another way to do this. So i've thought that maybe on each function (like voteup, votedown, write post, create topic etc) i'll be parsing a json to my logic and then from getting that json i'll be making some actions. But im not sure if its possible in C# and couldn't find any similar soultion on web. Maybe by making each function some kind of async i could get the goal? Or maybe some of you know a good tutorial or example with doing such a thing.

Comment: It's very hard to understand exactly what you're trying to achieve here - the question is very vague.

Comment: Hmm i'm looking for some ideas, how to get those all "activities" -> i got many random events in many different tables and i need to find a way to get all those events and give each event type (for example vote=1, post=2) and then in view show them ordered by date (for each type of event i'll show another msg)

Comment: None of that comes across in your question, and it still doesn't help to make it clearer, I'm afraid.

Comment: The problem is that it's the first task i'm actually not sure what i'm supposed to do. When i asked someone in work he said: "oh you have to find out how to do this by yourself". I'm looking here for some ideas what's the best way to get all user activities not doing this by database request.

Comment: Well I'm afraid you'll have to express yourself a *lot* more clearly in order to get any help. We have no idea what the database structure is, what your query does, or how JSON gets involved.

Comment: Ok so, when i'll come back home i'm gonna edit the question, providing more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend following something like [this specification](http://activitystrea.ms/). Instead of trying to determine what happened after the fact, literally log the actions in an "activity stream". Essentially, there's 4 parts to any action:

1. Actor
2. Verb
3. Object
4. Target

The bare minimum would be actor and verb, i.e. "John (actor) came online (verb)". Generally, there will also be an object, i.e. "John (actor) shared (verb) an article (object)." The target would be the entity acted upon: "John shared an article with Bill (target)". So you'll essentially have a table with those four columns, along with a timestamp of the activity. You can then extend that with columns to store URLs or other data related to the main four parts of the action. For example, you might have something like `ObjectUrl` which you would then fill with the URL to the article John shared, so that you could later link it. Also, since `actor`, `object` and `target` can often be users, you might want foreign keys to your user table so you can associate the actions directly with users. For example, you could query all activities where user "John" is the actor to get John's stream.

A lot of this is just going to come down to what you want to do with this information and how it will be utilized within the context of your application. This is more a framework to work off of than anything. The main point is to just record the actual activity somewhere instead of trying to run massive queries and such to attempt to suss out the activities after the fact.